Errors with Python program to translate word doc from English to French
I am very new to programming and am trying to use python 3.12.3 on Windows 11 to take a word doc file and translate it from English to French for a student of mine. It is a very large file (84,332kb) that I coverted from a PDF.
from docx import Document
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_docx(input_file, output_file):
    # Open the input Word document
    doc = Document(input_file)

    # Create a translator object
    translator = Translator()

    # Initialize an empty Document object for the translated document
    translated_doc = Document()

    # Translate each paragraph in the input document
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        # Translate the text from English to French
        translated_text = translator.translate(para.text, src='en', dest='fr').text
        
        # Add the translated text to the translated document
        translated_doc.add_paragraph(translated_text)

    # Save the translated document to the specified file
    translated_doc.save(output_file)


translate_docx(r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook.docx", r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook_french.docx")

I am getting this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shane\coding\new.py", line 26, in <module>
    translate_docx(r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook.docx", r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook_french.docx")
  File "C:\Users\shane\coding\new.py", line 17, in translate_docx
    translated_text = translator.translate(para.text, src='en', dest='fr').text
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 219, in translate
    parsed = json.loads(data[0][2])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

Any help would be appreciated as this is a bit above my skill level with python.
I have also tried this using the original PDF.
import fitz
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_pdf(input_file, output_file):
    # Open the input PDF file
    input_pdf = fitz.open(input_file)

    # Create a translator object
    translator = Translator()

    # Initialize an empty PDF writer
    output_pdf = fitz.open()

    # Iterate through each page of the input PDF
    for page_num in range(input_pdf.page_count):
        # Get the text of the current page
        page = input_pdf.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text()

        # Translate the text from English to French
        translated_text = translator.translate(text, src='en', dest='fr').text

        # Create a new page in the output PDF with the translated text
        output_page = output_pdf.new_page(width=page.rect.width, height=page.rect.height)
        output_page.insert_text((10, 10), translated_text)

    # Save the output PDF to the specified file
    output_pdf.save(output_file)

    # Close the input and output PDF files
    input_pdf.close()
    output_pdf.close()


translate_pdf(r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook.pdf", r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook_french.pdf")

and it resulted in this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shane\coding\PDF_English_French.py", line 35, in <module>
    translate_pdf(r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook.pdf", r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook_french.pdf")
  File "C:\Users\shane\coding\PDF_English_French.py", line 21, in translate_pdf
    translated_text = translator.translate(text, src='en', dest='fr').text
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 222, in translate
    translated_parts = list(map(lambda part: TranslatedPart(part[0], part[1] if len(part) >= 2 else []), parsed[1][0][0][5]))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 222, in <lambda>
    translated_parts = list(map(lambda part: TranslatedPart(part[0], part[1] if len(part) >= 2 else []), parsed[1][0][0][5]))
                                                            ~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range


I fix it. translated_text = translator.translate(para.text, dest='fr').text is the problem
Add .text to translated_doc.add_paragraph(translated_text.text)
By the way,translator can't read empty newline(for paragraph).
Error message: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType 
from docx import Document
from googletrans import Translator

def translate_docx(input_file, output_file):
    # Open the input Word document
    doc = Document(input_file)

    translator = Translator()

    translated_doc = Document()

    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        print(para.text)
        #If you want handle newline,just add_paragraph()
        if para.text=="":
            translated_doc.add_paragraph()
            continue

        translated_text = translator.translate(para.text, dest='fr')
        print(translated_text.text)
        
        translated_doc.add_paragraph(translated_text.text)

    translated_doc.save(output_file)

translate_docx(r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook.docx", r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook_french.docx")


Your fix above got the program to do the translation but ended with the following errors before saving the file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\shane\coding\new.py", line 26, in 
translate_docx(r"C:\Users\shane\coding\1.docx", r"C:\Users\shane\coding\amtg_handbook_french1.docx")
File "C:\Users\shane\coding\new.py", line 19, in translate_docx
translated_text = translator.translate(para.text, dest='fr')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 194, in translate
data, response = self._translate(text, dest, src)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 120, in _translate
r = self.client.post(url, params=params, data=data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py", line 824, in post
return self.request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py", line 600, in request
return self.send(
^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py", line 620, in send
response = self.send_handling_redirects(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py", line 647, in send_handling_redirects
response = self.send_handling_auth(
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py", line 684, in send_handling_auth
response = self.send_single_request(request, timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpx_client.py", line 714, in send_single_request
) = transport.request(

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection_pool.py", line 152, in request
response = connection.request(
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\connection.py", line 78, in request
return self.connection.request(method, url, headers, stream, timeout)
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\http2.py", line 118, in request
return h2_stream.request(method, url, headers, stream, timeout)

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\http2.py", line 292, in request
status_code, headers = self.receive_response(timeout)
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\http2.py", line 344, in receive_response
event = self.connection.wait_for_event(self.stream_id, timeout)
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\http2.py", line 197, in wait_for_event
self.receive_events(timeout)

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_sync\http2.py", line 204, in receive_events
data = self.socket.read(self.READ_NUM_BYTES, timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_backends\sync.py", line 60, in read
with map_exceptions(exc_map):

File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 158, in exit
self.gen.throw(value)
File "C:\Users\shane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\httpcore_exceptions.py", line 12, in map_exceptions
raise to_exc(exc) from None
httpcore._exceptions.ReadTimeout: The read operation timed out

Have you tried smaller file?
If my answer is useful,please upvote me.Thank you very much
